# How do I increase delay using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to initialize the delay time when the mouseenter.

I will attach my code and ask for your advice.

```
  $(".hasTopSubMenu").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
              $(this).find("ul").show();
              // reset delay time
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
              $(this).find("ul").delay(700).hide(0);                
        }
  });
```

Comment: Given that your `ul` is a descendant of `.hasTopSubMenu`, I'd imagine you could (and should) use CSS for this instead. It would likely handle your delay reset inherently.

Comment: Not very clear what you're trying to do but look into `dequeue()`. It's the only way to interrupt a `delay`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [clearQueue()](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/), check at the next implementation example:

```js
$(".hasTopSubMenu").on(
{
    mouseenter: function()
    {
        $(this).find("ul").clearQueue().show();              
    },
    mouseleave: function()
    {
        $(this).find("ul").delay(700).hide(0);                
    }
});
```

```css
.hasTopSubMenu {
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hasTopSubMenu">
  List
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```